# undefined method class_inheritable_accessor for ActiveRecord::Extensions::SqliteRegexp:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, activerecord

Ive recently install the '*ar-extension*' gem. After installation when i run *rails c* or *rails s* i gets the following error :

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/ar-extensions-0.9.2/lib/ar-extensions/extensions.rb:427:in `<class:SqliteRegexp>': undefined method `class_inheritable_accessor' for ActiveRecord::Extensions::SqliteRegexp:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/ar-extensions-0.9.2/lib/ar-extensions/extensions.rb:426:in `<module:Extensions>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/ar-extensions-0.9.2/lib/ar-extensions/extensions.rb:112:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/ar-extensions-0.9.2/init.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/ar-extensions-0.9.2/lib/ar-extensions.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /home/infibeam/Aptana_studio_3/workspace/DigitalAssetManagement/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've google for the error but in vain..Plz help me to know what xactly is going wrong.

Comment: actually ar-extensions doesnt work with rails3 for rails 3 we have <a href="https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import">activerecord-import</a> as the alternative and it works absolutely fine..;)

Comment: There are a number of close-votes on this question, I thought I'd explain why I vote against that. It's often hard to diagnose this kind of problem. It's not always clear that a gem is incompatible with a particular version of Rails. Having this error message here as a question makes it findable by others who are equally confused and need to have that head-slapping moment of "ah, it's just an incompatibility issue"... so I vote against closing this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gem you're trying to use is not compatible with rails 3.2. `class_inheritable_accessor` has been deprecated in favor of `class_attribute`.

You can look for rails 3.2 fork of this gem, do your own port, or search for substitutes.

Answer (score 1):

actually ar-extensions doesnt work with rails3 for rails 3 we have  [active import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) as the alternative and it works absolutely fine..;)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @JamesKhoury - actually, it does answer the question (the error tells us that the gem doesn't work with Rails3), and gives an alternative solution (a different gem)

Comment: @TarynEast Maybe it was the ambiguity of the question that led me to believe that this didn't answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a activerecord-import gem for rails 3

https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki

```
books = []
10.times do |i| 
  books  "book #{i}")
end
Book.import books
```